# Suppose T is a fixed labeled tree on $n$ vertices. how many labeled graphs on $n$ vertices have T as a subgraph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Suppose T is a fixed labeled tree on $n$ vertices. How many labeled graphs on $n$ vertices have T as a subgraph?

I know a tree is a graph in which all vertices have an edge and there are no circuits. And I know that a subgraph is a graph whose vertices and edges are subsets of another graph. But I'm not really sure how to think about this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The question amounts to asking in how many different ways you can add $0$ or more edges to $T$ without adding any vertices. HINT: A tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. The complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\binom{n}2$ edges; you can add any collection of those edges that aren’t already in $T$.